# Синхронизация DbSet с ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, база-данных, entity-framework, mvvm

возможно ли синхронизировать DbSet c ObservableCollection в MVVM таким образом, чтобы изменения в DbSet автоматически сохранялись в ObservableCollection без разрыва привязки при использовании DbSet.Local, если DbSet.Local вызывается в разных using?

Comment: Покажите пример кода, как вы заполняете коллекцию и пример модели данных. Вообще `using` уничтожает объект, а связка будет работать только пока объект жив.

Comment: спасибо, понятно. то есть, нужно работать с ObservableCollection? каким образом предпочтительнее заполнять - через конструктор или свойство?
allAircrafts = new ObservableCollection<Aircraft>(db.Aircrafts);